# Punctuation in Noun Phrase Extraction

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp, phrase

I am using OpenNLP to extract noun phrases from documents. In reviewing the output, I discovered that the phrase chunker ignores commas, leading to noun phrases that combine, for instance, multiple elements of a list into one phrase or two clauses in a sentence into one noun phrase. As a dummy example:

```
public class TestTokenizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String content = "dog, cat, fish, rat";
        String[] tokens = NLPToolsControllerOpenNLP.getInstance().getTokeniser().tokenize(content);
        String[] pos = NLPToolsControllerOpenNLP.getInstance().getPosTagger().tag(tokens);
        String[] phrases = NLPToolsControllerOpenNLP.getInstance().getPhraseChunker().chunk(tokens, pos);
        for(int i = 0; i<tokens.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Token: " + tokens[i] + " and POS: " + phrases[i]);
        }
        List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<String>();
        String phrase = "";
        for (int n = 0; n < tokens.length; n++) {
            if (phrases[n].equals("B-NP")) {
                phrase = tokens[n];
                for (int m = n + 1; m < tokens.length; m++) {
                    if (phrases[m].equals("I-NP")) {
                        phrase = phrase + " " + tokens[m];
                    } else {
                        n = m;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                phrase = phrase.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
                System.out.println("phrase: " + phrase);
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Token: dog and POS: B-NP
Token: , and POS: I-NP
Token: cat and POS: I-NP
Token: , and POS: I-NP
Token: fish and POS: I-NP
Token: , and POS: O
Token: rat and POS: B-NP
phrase: dog , cat , fish
phrase: rat
```

Parentheses have the same issue: because the chunker tags them with I-NP, I end up with noun phrases containing them.

The OpenNLP documentation says that "The **OpenNLP Sentence Detector** can detect that a punctuation character marks the end of a sentence or not." As such, I am a bit surprised that the phrase detector cannot detect the use of a comma or a parenthesis to mark the beginning or end of a phrase. Is there something I am missing here? Is there another approach that I should use? I am trying to avoid dealing with these issues on a case-by-case basis in a large corpus.

Comment: Comma doesn't always indicate a phrase boundary. For example, "Bob, Alice and John went to the market". "Bob" would not usually considered as a phrase.